# Floating action button not displaying properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.list.ListFragment">
    
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/no_data_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_no_data"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_data_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:text="@string/no_data"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no_data_imageView" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is displaying properly in android studio but is not aligned properly when running on a device or emulator. Even using the coordinator layout doesn't change the alignment on a device.
Can anyone please help me out with this. The answer isn't available anywhere. It is behaving differently on different devices.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: can you post a screen shot of how it looks like when "not aligned properly"?

Comment: I just uploaded the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your Layout file, hope it will work for you.
replace this code to your file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no_data_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/no_data_imageView"
        android:id="@+id/no_data_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@android:string/no"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no_data_imageView" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```